# PointCloud Component render issue fetch() custom data [react-three-fiber]

Tags: arrays, reactjs, graphics, fetch, react-three-fiber

Based on a snippet of original r3f-example found in [PointCloud.js](https://github.com/react-spring/react-three-fiber/blob/master/examples/src/demos/dev/Pointcloud.js)

Tested by myself, this above original component is able to render pointcloud by pushing individual `x y z` value into the for-loop in `Particle()` function.

I modified it and added a `fetch()' method to retrieve a custom data txt file, snippet as shown below,

```
...

export function Particles() {
  const [positions, colors] = useMemo(() => {
  let positions = [], colors = []
  positions.length = 3
  colors.length = 3

  const HEADER_SIZE = 4;
  let stream, longArray, len;
  let clusterCount ;
  let xy_size ;         
  let clusterSize = [];
  let XY_arr = [];      

  fetch(map)
  .then((r) => r.text())
  .then(text => {
    stream = text.toString().split("\n");     // split by next line
    longArray = stream.slice(2,);             // remove header from main longArray
    len = longArray.length;

    for (let i = 0, count = 0; i < len; i += HEADER_SIZE ) {
      xy_size = longArray.slice((i + HEADER_SIZE - 1), (i + HEADER_SIZE));            
      XY_arr.push(longArray.slice((i + HEADER_SIZE ), (i + HEADER_SIZE + xy_size*2)));    
      console.log(" Points in PointCloud " + count + ": " + xy_size );
      clusterSize.push(xy_size);
      clusterCount = count;
      i += xy_size*2; 
      count ++;          
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < (clusterCount-2); i++) {  
      for (let j = 0; j < clusterSize[i]*2; j+=2) {  
        positions.push( XY_arr[i][j] )
        positions.push(0)
        positions.push( XY_arr[i][j+1] ) 
        colors.push(1)
        colors.push(0.5)
        colors.push(0.5)
        console.log( XY_arr[i][j] );
      }
    }
  }       
)
  return [new Float32Array(positions), new Float32Array(colors)]
}, [])

...
...
```

, `map` is the custom text file in string, with single data line-by-line

The `fetch()` method is able to read a custom pointcloud file into `XY_arr` as an object of `Array()`. I have checked that `XY_arr[i][j]` in the nested-forloop are able to return correct `x` and `z` value in console.

Current problem is that no pointcloud being rendered onto `<Canvas />`

Is the problem caused by `position.push()` nested loop being inside of 'fetch()' method ? And how to resolve. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

better use const [state, set] = useState() and then fetch in useEffect calling "set" when you're done. putting an async fetch request inside useMemo is practically a side-effect in the render function - which isn't good, nor will it work like that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for late reply. However, I need to parse a array fetched from a dir, and not changing useMemo method.  I realized I can actually print out PointCloud with const = { [ARRAY] } . So, is it possible to async fetch and update the ARRAY dynamically?